# Extract certain part of name in string

Tags: r

Im trying to extract particular part of names in a column of `DF`

```
DF
a           b
a.b.c_tot   1
b.c.d_tot   2
d.e.g_tot   3
```

I need to extract letter between `.` and `_tot`, so that

```
DF
a           b   c
a.b.c_tot   1   c
b.c.d_tot   2   d 
d.e.g_tot   3   g
```

I suppose it could be done with `sub` as i have learnt today how to extract the letter before first `.`, but how to extract "middle" part of the name?
I was reading `sub` explanation and help but all my trials results in just copying full name of `a` to `c`.
Thank you for any tips.

Comment: You may use `substring()` function if you want to extract that letter.

Comment: Thank you, substring() did the work! and seems much easier than sub :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can call `sub()` to match the entire string, starting with (1) any number of any characters, then (2) a literal dot, then (3) use a capture group to capture the following character, then (4) a literal `_tot`. We can then use the `\1` backreference atom (with the backslash properly backslash-escaped as per R's string encoding rules) to replace the entire string with the captured character.

```
DF$c <- sub('^.*\\.(.)_tot$','\\1',DF$a);
DF;
##           a b c
## 1 a.b.c_tot 1 c
## 2 b.c.d_tot 2 d
## 3 d.e.g_tot 3 g
```

---

Yes, I see the problem; if `DF$a` were to contain values that do not match the expected pattern, the `sub()` call would pass them through to the new `DF$c` column. Here's a hacky solution using the [Perl branch reset](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#(?|pattern)) feature:

```
DF <- data.frame(a=c('a.b.c_tot','b.c.d_tot','d.e.g_tot','non-matching'),b=c(1L,2L,3L,4L),stringsAsFactors=F);
DF$c <- sub(perl=T,'(?|^.*\\.(.)_tot$|^.*$())','\\1',DF$a);
DF;
##              a b c
## 1    a.b.c_tot 1 c
## 2    b.c.d_tot 2 d
## 3    d.e.g_tot 3 g
## 4 non-matching 4
```

Here's a better solution, involving storing the regex in a variable in advance, and using `grepl()` and `replace()` to replace non-matching values with NA prior to calling `sub()`:

```
re <- '^.*\\.(.)_tot$';
DF$c <- sub(re,'\\1',replace(DF$a,!grepl(re,DF$a),NA));
DF;
##              a b    c
## 1    a.b.c_tot 1    c
## 2    b.c.d_tot 2    d
## 3    d.e.g_tot 3    g
## 4 non-matching 4 <NA>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it returns me whole name as well.

Answer (score 2):

Use `regexpr` and `regmatches` with a lookbehind and lookahead regex.

```
x <- c("a.b.c_tot", "b.c.d_tot", "d.e.g_tot")
regmatches(x, regexpr("(?<=\\.).(?=_tot)", x, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "c" "d" "g"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
DF$c <- str_extract(DF$a, "\\w(?=_tot)")
DF$c
#[1] "c" "d" "g"
```